# Verify my proof: For an invertible $A$ , $V\in F^n$ is an invariant subspace $V$ of $A$ $\iff$ $V$ is an invariant subspace $V$ of $Adj(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, adjoint-operators

$$
v_0,v_1\in V
$$
$$
V \text{ is an }A\text{-invariant subspace}
$$ 
$$
Av_0=v_1
$$
$$\iff$$
$$
A^{-1}Av_0=v_0=A^{-1}v_1
$$

---

$\text{Using }A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\operatorname {det}(A)}\operatorname{Adj}(A)\text{  :}$

---

$$\iff$$
$$\frac{1}{\operatorname {det}(A)}\operatorname{Adj}(A)v_1=v_0$$
$$\iff$$
$$\operatorname{Adj}(A)v_1={\operatorname {det}(A)}v_0$$
$${\operatorname {det}(A)}v_0\in V$$

---

Does this seal the proof that $V$ is an $\operatorname {Adj}(A)$ invariant subspace?

Comment: Slightly, very slightly confusing in my opinion, but it looks right to me. +1

Comment: why is it right? where have you proved that $Adj(A)v_0\in V$?

Comment: @Exodd I think he proved Adj$\,v_1=kv_0\in V\;,\;\;k=\det A\;$ , and from the beginning $\;v_0,v_1\in V\;$ . This means invariance of the matrix Adj$\,A\;$ . The "slightly confusing" I mentioned above is related to the (non) use of quantifiers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, I think your proof is correct though slightly confusing. I'd propose the following:

We're given that for all $\;v\in V\;$ there exists $\;u\in V\;$ such that $\;Av=u\;$ , and from here we get that $\;A^{-1}u=v\implies V\;$ is also $\;A^{-1}\,-$ invariant. Observe that since that since $\;A\;$ is an isomorphism, for any $\;u\in V\;$ there is **always one single** $\;v\in V\;$ such that $\;Av=u\;$, and this is so because we're given $\;AV\subset V\implies AV=V\;$ as we're in finite dimension and $\;A\;$ is bijective.

After that what you did is just fine, I believe.